# finding odd element from 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am expecting output as 2,5 but getting output as 2,3 from the code below.Can anyone  suggest solution and please point where i have got wrong

```
<?php
$k=0;
$array1=Array(1,2,3);
$array2=Array(1,3,5);
$array3=Array();

for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++)
{
    if(!in_array($array1[$i],$array2))
    {
        if(!in_array($array1[$i],$array3))
        {
            $array3[$k]=$array1[$i];
            $k++;
        }
    }
}

for($j=0;$j<count($array2);$j++)
{
    if(!in_array($array2[$j],$array1))
    {
        if(!in_array($array2[$j],$array3))
        {
            $array3[$k]=$array1[$j];
            $k++;
        }
    }
}

print_r($array3);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get the unique values from each array and then combine them into one final array:

```
$array1=Array(1,2,3);
$array2=Array(1,3,5);
$unique1 = array_diff($array1, $array2);
$unique2 = array_diff($array2, $array1);
$unique = array_merge($unique1, $unique2);
print_r($unique1); // Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 5 )
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CsnmBd)

Comment: i dont want to use inbuilt function

Comment: Why not? That makes no sense.

Comment: `+=` will fail when the unique arrays have overlapping indexes. http://codepad.viper-7.com/OyNwYW

Answer (score 1):

In your second loop, you're using `$array1[$j]` where it should be `$array2[$j]`.

```
for($j=0;$j<count($array2);$j++)
{
    if(!in_array($array2[$j],$array1))
    {
        if(!in_array($array2[$j],$array3))
        {
            $array3[$k]=$array2[$j]; // this is where the fix is
            $k++;
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/rPCNe)

That being said, John is definitely correct that you should be using `array_diff()`.

Comment: nice one thanks..just while making copy of first for loop i made a mistake..by the way thanks for showing it